# "error parsing query: found %, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 7"}

Tags: python, influxdb, influxql

When I try to parse this query in influxDB from python, I get this error.

> {"error":"error parsing query: found %, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 7"}

How do I resolve this issue?

Here’s my query:

```
data ='q=select "time","T(C)","RH(\%)" from PM_histo WHERE time >= \'2022-05-04T11:00:00Z\' and time <= \'2022-05-04T11:10:00Z\' order by time asc'
```

I tried also with escape character but same error occurs

Please see below the json

[image: 1]

Comment: To get a literal `%` use `%%`, not `\%`

Comment: Hello enke, i try this right now, still the same error :(

Comment: You already have it (`%`) inside double quotes. Do you need really need to quote it again?

Comment: I tried with several ways to escape the char is any other way to query a special char?